# setup transaction replication in cross domain

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm trying to setup transaction replication between two domains under the same active directory.  The publisher server is in a DR site domain and the remote distribution server is in the main site domain with the subscriber. Here are the machine names

> Publisher Server : publisher1.drsite.mycompany.com
>
> Distribution Server : distributor1.mainsite.mycompany.com
>
> Subscriber Server : subscriber1.mainsite.mycompany.com

When I try to add `publisher1.drsite.mycompany.com` to the remote distributor, it will not accept the FQDN and gives me the error below under Replication.Utilities

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server.  Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, "publisher1"

Does anyone experience the same problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a CNAME in your DNS at  your primary SERVER putting the DR server's hostname.  This way publisher.mainsite.mycompany.com can be resolved.  Then use publisher as the hostname to use when connecting.